# Unable to simulate the crash from the crash log shared by customer in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, crash, symbolicatecrash

I am not able to find the crash point from this crash log, and not even able to simulate the crash from the crash log which was shared by the customers using the app from the appstore.

The application shows that it "Failed to resume in time". I am not able to reproduce the same crash, and i don't know the reason for why it's occurring.

Please let me know if there is any way to simulate this crash from the log.

Please find the log below

```
Incident Identifier: CB35BB36-2366-4907-B3B2-58D7D8F849C5
Hardware Model:      iPad2,3
Process:         myAppMobile [1390]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/B19D15B8-3874-497F-8EC5-00DADD84F597/myAppMobile.app/myAppMobile
Identifier:      myAppMobile
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-09-20 09:30:20.510 -0500
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
com.sample.myAppMobile failed to resume in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 1.230 (user 1.230, system 0.000), 6% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.042, 0% CPU

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a71b0fc __psynch_mutexwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a664124 pthread_mutex_lock + 388
2   WebCore                         0x382c04ac _WebTryThreadLock(bool) + 332
3   WebCore                         0x382c13b2 WebThreadLock + 62
4   UIKit                           0x3430fe92 -[UIWebDocumentView dealloc] + 118
5   UIKit                           0x344f444a -[UIWebBrowserView dealloc] + 350
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a6344b4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a6391b8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 220
8   CoreFoundation                  0x3237af36 __CFRunLoopRun + 1286
9   CoreFoundation                  0x322edeb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
10  CoreFoundation                  0x322edd44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
11  Foundation                      0x32c10f92 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 250
12  myAppMobile                 0x001870b8 -[ViewWeb webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:] (ViewWeb.m:2679)
13  UIKit                           0x3441d384 -[UIWebView webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:] + 368
14  CoreFoundation                  0x323aa9c0 __invoking___ + 64
15  CoreFoundation                  0x32301fe6 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 282
16  CoreFoundation                  0x32301b3e -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 46
17  WebKit                          0x38bed5d0 -[_WebSafeForwarder forwardInvocation:] + 244
18  CoreFoundation                  0x323a9616 ___forwarding___ + 622
19  CoreFoundation                  0x32300f64 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 20
20  WebKit                          0x38bff934 WebFrameLoaderClient::dispatchDecidePolicyForNavigationAction(void (WebCore::PolicyChecker::*)(WebCore::PolicyAction), WebCore::NavigationAction const&, WebCore::ResourceRequest const&, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::FormState>) + 212
21  WebCore                         0x3833098c WebCore::PolicyChecker::checkNavigationPolicy(WebCore::ResourceRequest const&, WebCore::DocumentLoader*, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::FormState>, void (*)(void*, WebCore::ResourceRequest const&, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::FormState>, bool), void*) + 536
22  WebCore                         0x38330388 WebCore::FrameLoader::loadWithDocumentLoader(WebCore::DocumentLoader*, WebCore::FrameLoadType, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::FormState>) + 920
23  WebCore                         0x3832fd2a WebCore::FrameLoader::loadWithNavigationAction(WebCore::ResourceRequest const&, WebCore::NavigationAction const&, bool, WebCore::FrameLoadType, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::FormState>) + 406
24  WebCore                         0x383d78fe WebCore::FrameLoader::loadURL(WebCore::KURL const&, WTF::String const&, WTF::String const&, bool, WebCore::FrameLoadType, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::FormState>) + 862
25  WebCore                         0x383da314 WebCore::FrameLoader::loadFrameRequest(WebCore::FrameLoadRequest const&, bool, bool, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::FormState>, WebCore::ShouldSendReferrer) + 580
26  WebCore                         0x383da058 WebCore::FrameLoader::urlSelected(WebCore::FrameLoadRequest const&, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>, bool, bool, WebCore::ShouldSendReferrer, WebCore::ShouldReplaceDocumentIfJavaScriptURL) + 456
27  WebCore                         0x3854ee62 WebCore::FrameLoader::urlSelected(WebCore::KURL const&, WTF::String const&, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>, bool, bool, WebCore::ShouldSendReferrer) + 150
28  WebCore                         0x3854ed12 WebCore::HTMLAnchorElement::handleClick(WebCore::Event*) + 634
29  WebCore                         0x384e4d50 WebCore::HTMLAnchorElement::defaultEventHandler(WebCore::Event*) + 400
30  WebCore                         0x382e1bc2 WebCore::EventDispatcher::dispatchEvent(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>) + 894
31  WebCore                         0x382e181a WebCore::EventDispatchMediator::dispatchEvent(WebCore::EventDispatcher*) const + 26
32  WebCore                         0x382e17de WebCore::EventDispatcher::dispatchEvent(WebCore::Node*, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::EventDispatchMediator>) + 94
33  WebCore                         0x382e170e WebCore::Node::dispatchEvent(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>) + 30
34  WebCore                         0x384966bc WebCore::EventTarget::dispatchEvent(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>, int&) + 68
35  WebCore                         0x38496608 WebCore::jsNodePrototypeFunctionDispatchEvent(JSC::ExecState*) + 148
36  JavaScriptCore                  0x363a27dc llint_native_call_trampoline + 56
37  JavaScriptCore                  0x36273bb8 JSC::arrayProtoFuncForEach(JSC::ExecState*) + 496
38  JavaScriptCore                  0x363a27dc llint_native_call_trampoline + 56
39  JavaScriptCore                  0x3627eb06 JSC::call(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 46
40  WebCore                         0x383d3872 WebCore::JSEventListener::handleEvent(WebCore::ScriptExecutionContext*, WebCore::Event*) + 642
41  WebCore                         0x383d3526 WebCore::EventTarget::fireEventListeners(WebCore::Event*, WebCore::EventTargetData*, WTF::Vector<WebCore::RegisteredEventListener, 1ul>&) + 270
42  WebCore                         0x382e2056 WebCore::EventTarget::fireEventListeners(WebCore::Event*) + 46
43  WebCore                         0x382e2146 WebCore::Node::handleLocalEvents(WebCore::Event*) + 58
44  WebCore                         0x38386276 WebCore::EventContext::handleLocalEvents(WebCore::Event*) const + 58
45  WebCore                         0x382e19f8 WebCore::EventDispatcher::dispatchEvent(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>) + 436
46  WebCore                         0x382e181a WebCore::EventDispatchMediator::dispatchEvent(WebCore::EventDispatcher*) const + 26
47  WebCore                         0x382e17de WebCore::EventDispatcher::dispatchEvent(WebCore::Node*, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::EventDispatchMediator>) + 94
48  WebCore                         0x382e170e WebCore::Node::dispatchEvent(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>) + 30
49  WebCore                         0x384966bc WebCore::EventTarget::dispatchEvent(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>, int&) + 68
50  WebCore                         0x3855905c WebCore::EventHandler::dispatchTouchEvent(WebCore::PlatformTouchEvent const&, WTF::AtomicString const&, WTF::HashMap<WebCore::EventTarget*, WTF::Vector<WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::Touch>, 0ul>*, WTF::PtrHash<WebCore::EventTarget*>, WTF::HashTraits<WebCore::EventTarget*>, WTF::HashTraits<WTF::Vector<WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::Touch>, 0ul>*> > const&, float, float) + 644
51  WebCore                         0x38558566 WebCore::EventHandler::handleTouchEvent(WebCore::PlatformTouchEvent const&) + 3478
52  WebCore                         0x38556bb0 WebCore::EventHandler::touchEvent(WebEvent*) + 100
53  WebKit                          0x38c4b5f8 -[WebHTMLView touch:] + 148
54  WebCore                         0x3854c4a4 -[WAKView _selfHandleEvent:] + 132
55  WebCore                         0x3854c410 -[WAKView handleEvent:] + 56
56  WebCore                         0x3854c1d0 -[WAKWindow sendEventSynchronously:] + 432
57  UIKit                           0x344f554e -[UIWebBrowserView _dispatchWebEvent:] + 74
58  UIKit                           0x344f593e -[UIWebBrowserView _webTouchEventsRecognized:] + 442
59  UIKit                           0x344f3de0 -[UIWebTouchEventsGestureRecognizer _processTouches:withEvent:type:] + 288
60  UIKit                           0x344f3f34 -[UIWebTouchEventsGestureRecognizer touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 52
61  UIKit                           0x341c20de -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 502
62  UIKit                           0x341c1dae -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 86
63  UIKit                           0x341af7fc -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 376
64  UIKit                           0x341af116 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6150
65  GraphicsServices                0x35ea55a0 _PurpleEventCallback + 588
66  CoreFoundation                  0x3237c680 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
67  CoreFoundation                  0x3237bf7a __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 358
68  CoreFoundation                  0x3237acb2 __CFRunLoopRun + 642
69  CoreFoundation                  0x322edeb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
70  CoreFoundation                  0x322edd44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
71  GraphicsServices                0x35ea42e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
72  UIKit                           0x342032fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
73  myAppMobile                 0x000e27a2 main (main.m:18)
74  myAppMobile                 0x000b8104 start + 36

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a70b648 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a63b974 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 792
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a63b654 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 32

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a71b0fc __psynch_mutexwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a664124 pthread_mutex_lock + 388
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x363206ba JSC::JSLock::lock() + 138
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x363206fe JSC::JSLockHolder::JSLockHolder(JSC::JSGlobalData*) + 22
4   WebCore                         0x383cab5c WebCore::ScheduledAction::executeFunctionInContext(JSC::JSGlobalObject*, JSC::JSValue, WebCore::ScriptExecutionContext*) + 28
5   WebCore                         0x383caac6 WebCore::ScheduledAction::execute(WebCore::Document*) + 118
6   WebCore                         0x383ca75c WebCore::DOMTimer::fired() + 264
7   WebCore                         0x3835103e WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFiredInternal() + 134
8   WebCore                         0x38350f82 WebCore::timerFired(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 62
9   CoreFoundation                  0x3237c5dc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 12
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3237c28c __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 268
11  CoreFoundation                  0x3237aefc __CFRunLoopRun + 1228
12  CoreFoundation                  0x322edeb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
13  CoreFoundation                  0x322edd44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
14  WebCore                         0x382be500 RunWebThread(void*) + 440
15  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a67430e _pthread_start + 306
16  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a6741d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a71b594 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x323801f2 __CFSocketManager + 674
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a67430e _pthread_start + 306
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a6741d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a70aeb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a70b048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3237c040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3237ad9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                  0x322edeb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x322edd44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   Foundation                      0x32c3a3d0 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 304
7   Foundation                      0x32cbde80 __NSThread__main__ + 968
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a67430e _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a6741d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a71b08c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a66cd2a _pthread_cond_wait + 642
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a66caa0 pthread_cond_timedwait + 40
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x3629ac70 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 104
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x363ac552 JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 78
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x363befa8 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a67430e _pthread_start + 306
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a6741d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 6 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a71b08c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a66cd2a _pthread_cond_wait + 642
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a676f14 pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x3633ff3c JSC::SlotVisitor::drainFromShared(JSC::SlotVisitor::SharedDrainMode) + 144
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x3633fe7c JSC::MarkStackThreadSharedData::markingThreadMain() + 140
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x363befa8 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a67430e _pthread_start + 306
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a6741d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 7 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a70aeb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a70b048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3237c040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3237ad9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                  0x322edeb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x322edd44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x38358d02 WebCore::runLoaderThread(void*) + 138
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x363befa8 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a67430e _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a6741d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 8 name:  WebCore: LocalStorage
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a71b08c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a66cd2a _pthread_cond_wait + 642
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a676f14 pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x3629ac42 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 58
4   WebCore                         0x384d2e88 WTF::PassOwnPtr<WebCore::StorageTask> WTF::MessageQueue<WebCore::StorageTask>::waitForMessageFilteredWithTimeout<bool (WebCore::StorageTask*)>(WTF::MessageQueueWaitResult&, bool (&)(WebCore::StorageTask*), double) + 52
5   WebCore                         0x384d2e3c WebCore::StorageThread::threadEntryPoint() + 120
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x363befa8 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a67430e _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a6741d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a71bd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a669cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a669a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a6698a0 start_wqthread + 4

Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1

Binary Images:
```

Code Snippet (crash point : Line number 2679)

```
if (!self.urlConnection)
                {
                    NSLog(@"shouldStartLoadWithRequest urlConnection");

                    self.urlConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];     
                }


                // Create auto-release pool and wait for response from NSURLConnection to set isWaitingForResponse to NO
                while (isWaitingForResponse)
                {
                    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

                    // Line no 2679
                    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];

                    [pool drain];
                    NSLog(@"shouldStartLoadWithRequest still isWaitingForResponse");
                }
```

Comment: Try to symbolicate crash report, as described in the answer by Sachin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports/17747804#17747804

Comment: It seems like your app is freezing after executing this, `-[ViewWeb webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:] (ViewWeb.m:2679)` culprit is code in `ViewWeb.m` @ line number:2679. It is difficult to say why it is freezing without looking at code.

Comment: It's a deadlock; both `com.apple.main-thread` and `WebThread` look like they are both attempting to lock the same mutex.  It won't be easy to replicate but something, somewhere is not properly waiting its turn... and it looks like it might be in the javascript.

Comment: ... look for calls to methods like `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` and check if they are running on the non-main thread.

Comment: Thanks all. @Amar : I have shared the code snippet of the crash location.

Comment: @vshankar Are you making synchronous call in `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` method?

Comment: Yes i am making synchronous call in `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` method.

Comment: @vshankar That is the reason for you app getting killed, as a sync network call on main thread will block it. Fyi, please tag using @<name> so that the person will get notified when you reply to his/her comment.

Comment: @Amar : If you could see the code snippet you could see that I am making async call while requesting for the url. `self.urlConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self]; `. Sorry initially i was confused if NSURLConnection is syncronous or async.

Comment: @vshankar Yes, but why then you are blocking the current runloop (main thread)?

Comment: @Amar: The currentloop is added so that the connection runs properly and the thread doesn't disappear untill the connection gets complete response.

Comment: @vshankar Why are you taking such an approach? What is the requirement, could you elaborate? May be I can help.